# AutoMapper not getting mapped

Tags: c#

My First day with AutoMapper, I am trying to map an object with a database table but it's not mapping and my list is empty, This is how I am trying,

```
    public static void MapFromDB()
    {
        someDataAccess da = new someDataAccess();
        someSolution.DataAccess.Clients.Fruit_CrateDataTable dt = da.GetFruitCratesTable(999);

        List<FruitCrate> a = new List<FruitCrate>();
        Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
        Mapper.DynamicMap(dt, a);
        Console.WriteLine("Done");
    }

    public class FruitCrate
    { 
        public int ID;
        public int DeliveryID;
        public int DriverID;
        public int NumberOfFruits;
        public int RottenFruits;
        public int BadCats;
        public string CatsName;
        public string CatsDescription;
        public string CatDadName;
    }
```

**What I am expecting**

I am expecting to get List with list items that are in DataTable

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: @ArijitMukherjee from my question "but it's not mapping and my list is empty" thank you :)

Comment: You are trying to map from a type of `Fruit_CrateDataTable` to a list of type `FruitCrate` I suspect Mapper is missing information of how to do it. DynamicMap might not be enough for this scenario.